# Can we extract positrons from gamma rays?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, antimatter, gamma-rays

If gamma rays undergo pair production is there a way to say, deflect and collect the positrons using magnetic fields?

Comment: yes, the problem is more likely to be getting a strong enough source of gamma rays

Comment: And, since the electron and positron are heading in opposite directions with opposite charge, they will both deflect towards the same direction (assuming a constant magnetic field).

Comment: [This PDF from the snowmass process](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/accel/nlc/zdr/Snowmass96/ZDRCH03.PDF) describes conceptual design of a positron source for the NLC (Next Linear Collider; clever name, eh?) which is modeled as a improvement on the SLAC positron source. The SLAC sources evidently uses an electron beam to generate showers rather than a gamma source, presumably because electron beams are easy to create and manipulate on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a **magnetic** field, you are better off using a strong **electric** field to separate them - since the initial direction of the electron / positron is somewhat random, a magnetic field will deflect but not separate in a meaningful way. An electric field can pull the positrons one way, and the electrons the other way - regardless of their initial direction. Thus the positrons can always be directed towards your "collector"; of course you will need a confinement device (magnetic, presumably) which means you will ultimately need both. But if you use just a magnetic field, you will trap both electrons and positrons and they won't stay apart for long - it's not in their nature.